# Como solucionar este error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel

miren tengo una función la cual activa una evidencia y necesito que después de activar me redireccione a la lista de evidencias, para esto necesito el id de la ficha, que es como el curso, lo que pasa es que no puedo pasarle ese id en la url, así que pensé en hacer una consulta y de ahí obtener el id, pero me aparece el siguiente error:

**Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string**

Esta es la función:

````
public function activarEvidencias($id){
        Evidencia_ficha::where('idEvidencia_ficha', '=', $id)
                   ->update([
                       'estadoEvidencia' => 1
                   ]);
        
        // Obtener el id de la ficha para llevarla a la lista de evidencias
        $idFicha = DB::table('evidencia_fichas')
                   ->join('fichas', 'evidencia_fichas.idFichaFK', '=', 'fichas.idFicha')
                   ->where('evidencia_fichas.idFichaFK', '=', $id)
                   ->get('idFicha');

        return redirect('/instructor/evidencias/'.$idFicha[0]);
    } ```
````

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea del error? Estarías intentando usar un objeto como si fuera una cadena. Haz un `dd($id);` y dinos qué muestra. Quizá debas pasar solamente el valor del `id` a esa función y no un objeto completo.

Comment: ¿Qué muestra el debug que te sugerí antes? Haz también este debug y nos dices: `dd($idFicha);`

Comment: El error sale de la linea del return y me muestras esto:

Comment: #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#1261 ▼
      +"idFicha": 1
    }
    1 => {#1270 ▼
      +"idFicha": 1
    }
    2 => {#1271 ▼
      +"idFicha": 1
    }
  ]

Comment: ¿Cuál de los dos debug muestra eso? ¿Puedes cambiarlos por `var_dump` en vez de `dd`? Es que no entiendo mucho las salidas de Laravel :)

Comment: Sospecho que `$idFicha` es un objeto y la forma de acceder a la propiedad sería esta: `$idFicha[0]->idFicha` pero como ya dije, no soy experto en Laravel, si veo un `var_dump` te lo podría decir con más propiedad.

Comment: Si me funciono con el $idFicha[0]->idFicha, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

El error:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Ocurre cuando intentas usar un objeto como si fuese una cadena.

Cuando eso ocurra haz un debug del/los elementos que están en la línea del error y analízalo.

Si el debug te muestra esto:

```
#items: array:3 [▼ 
                   0 => {#1261 ▼ +"idFicha": 1 } 
                   1 => {#1270 ▼ +"idFicha": 1 } 
                   2 => {#1271 ▼ +"idFicha": 1 } 
                ]
```

Significa que `$idFicha` es un array de objetos con una propiedad `idFicha`, y que si quieres acceder a esa propiedad en el objeto que está en el ìndice `0` del array debes hacerlo así:

```
$idFicha[0]->idFicha
```